# Кто может помочь с проверкой ВУ (водительского удостоверения) через ГИБДД по API?

Tags: recaptcha

После повышения уровня капчи, не можем получить доступ для массовых проверок. Есть ли у кого решение? Может кто уже нашел способ?

Comment: Меняй IP, то есть используй прокси

Comment: если бы все так просто было-)